# Debugging python code to retrieve rest api access token

Tags: python, api, rest

Good morning. My first time posting here, so bear with me. I am writing a python script to interact with a rest api server. I am neither an expert on python or an expert on rest :) I am working from a vendor example that is supposed to retrieve an access token but the contents of the response don't seem to have the access token.
This is not the entire program, but this is the pertinent portion.

```
...
r = requests.post(api_endpoint, data=payload, verify=False)
print("Requested API End Point: ",api_endpoint)
print("Requested URL: ",tasks_url)
print("Response Code: ",r.status_code)
print("Encoding: ",r.encoding)
print("URL: ",r.url)
print("==============================================")
print("Content: ",r.text)
print("JSON: ",r.json)
print("==============================================")

#Auth token to be used by successive requests
my_token = r.json()['access_token']
...
```

When the contents are printed, this is the output:

```
Requested API End Point:  https://10.17.220.18/webadmin/api/v1/token
Requested URL:  https://10.17.220.18/webadmin/api/v1/tasks
Response Code:  200
Encoding:  ISO-8859-1
URL:  https://10.17.220.18/
==============================================
Content:  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MOVEit Automation</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  <meta name="application-name" content="MOVEit Automation Web Admin"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.6cc85e0e6cb38470ac35.css"></head>
<body>
  <div class="text_wrap_word_break" growl></div>

  <ui-view></ui-view>
<script src="runtime.1abade75be5da749f775.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.7266e4bdf7a11e80aa90.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills.c47513d120861ef56c55.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.9bb9cd329657fea056b0.js" defer></script><script src="main.ce5aa180c8773cfe8736.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

But when I attempt to grab the token it fails as if the json object were type "none"

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

It points to the line:
my_token = r.json()['access_token']

My goal is to use this token for subsequent requests.
Again, sorry if this is not enough/too much information. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: In most cases the token will be return in r.text, I have a question do you have an option to get JSON format from the vendor ,try to add           headers={
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'}

Comment: and change requests.post(api_endpoint, data=payload, verify=False) to requests.post(api_endpoint, data=payload,headers=headers, verify=False)

Comment: Maybe you need to provide some specific headers? Your code ‘functions’ so that isn’t the problem, so the problem is the content being provided which doesn’t meet the requirements of the API endpoint - starting with authentication, probably. Can you access the endpoint successfully by any method? If through a browser, you can trace the communicatioin using e.g. Telerik Fiddler and then reproduce the same details using your Python code.

Comment: thanks folks, will be working through this next few days